# C++: template to check if expression compiles

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, specialization, partial-specialization

When writing template specialization with SFINAE you often come to the point where you need to write a whole new specialization because of one small not-existing member or function. I would like to pack this selection into a small statement like `orElse<T a,T b>`.

small example:

```
template<typename T> int get(T& v){
    return orElse<v.get(),0>();
}
```

is this possible?

Comment: If you don't tag C++, hardly anybody will look at this.

Comment: Could you specify a little more? Sounds like something for `std::conditional`...

Comment: unique question, highly useful if exists, c'mon people, show this question some love

Comment: if you put an expression into a template it has to compile, because otherwise the compiler skips the whole template (or template specialization). so if i write something like orElse<a+23*b.f(),0> it couldnt consider the second expression ( 0) because of any errors in the first expression. i wanted to know if this is possible with some tricks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intent of `orElse<v.get(),0>()` is clear enough, but if such a thing could exist,
it would have to be be one of:

**Invocation Lineup**

```
orElse(v,&V::get,0)
orElse<V,&V::get>(v,0)
orElse<V,&V::get,0>(v)
```

where `v` is of type `V`, and the function template thus instantiated
would be respectively:

**Function Template Lineup**

```
template<typename T>
int orElse(T & obj, int(T::pmf*)(), int deflt);

template<typename T, int(T::*)()>
int orElse(T & obj, int deflt);

template<typename T, int(T::*)(), int Default>
int orElse(T & obj);
```

As you appreciate, no such a thing can exist with the effect that you want.

For any anyone who doesn't get that, 
the reason is simply this: None of the function invocations in the **Invocation Lineup**
will compile if there is no such member as `V::get`. There's no getting round
that, and the fact that the function invoked might be an instantiation of a 
function template in the **Function Template Lineup** makes no difference whatever. 
If `V::get` does not exist, then any code that mentions it will not compile.

However, you seem to have a practical goal that need not be approached
in just this hopeless way. It looks as if, for a given name `foo` and an given type `R`, 
you want to be able to write just one function template:

```
template<typename T, typename ...Args>
R foo(T && obj, Args &&... args);
```

which will return the value of `R(T::foo)`, called upon `obj` with arguments `args...`,
if such a member function exists, and otherwise return some default `R`.

If that's right, it can be achieved as per the following illustration:

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

namespace detail {

template<typename T>

T default_ctor()
{
    return T();
}

// SFINAE `R(T::get)` exists
template<typename T, typename R, R(Default)(), typename ...Args>
auto get_or_default(
    T && obj,
    Args &&... args) ->
    std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_same<R,decltype(obj.get(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
    >::value,R>
{
    return obj.get(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

// SFINAE `R(T::get)` does not exist
template<typename T, typename R, R(Default)(), typename ...Args>
R get_or_default(...)
{
    return Default();
}

} //namespace detail


// This is your universal `int get(T,Args...)`
template<typename T, typename ...Args>
int get(T && obj, Args &&... args)
{
    return detail::get_or_default<T&,int,detail::default_ctor>
        (obj,std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

// C++14, trivially adaptable for C++11
```

which can be tried out with:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    A(){};
    int get() {
        return 1;
    }
    int get(int i) const  {
        return i + i;
    }
};

struct B
{
    double get() {
        return 2.2;
    }
    double get(double d) {
        return d * d;
    }
};

struct C{};

int main()
{
    A const aconst;
    A a;
    B b;
    C c;
    cout << get(aconst) << endl;    // expect 0
    cout << get(a) << endl;         // expect 1 
    cout << get(b) << endl;         // expect 0
    cout << get(c) << endl;         // expect 0
    cout << get(a,1) << endl;       // expect 2
    cout << get(b,2,2) << endl;     // expect 0
    cout << get(c,3) << endl;       // expect 0
    cout << get(A(),2) << endl;     // expect 4
    cout << get(B(),2,2) << endl;   // expect 0
    cout << get(C(),3) << endl;     // expect 0
    return 0;
}
```

There is "compound SFINAE" in play in the complicated return type:

```
std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_same<R,decltype(obj.get(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
    >::value,R>
```

If `T::get` does not exist then `decltype(obj.get(std::forward<Args>(args)...)`
does not compile. But if it does compile, and the return-type of `T::get` is
something other than `R`, then the `std::enable_if_t` type specifier does not
compile. Only if the member function exists and has the desired return type `R`
can the `R(T::get)` *exists* case be instantiated. Otherwise the 
catch-all `R(T::get)` *does not exist* case is chosen.

Notice that `get(aconst)` returns 0 and not 1. That's as it should be,
because the non-const overload `A::get()` cannot be called on a const `A`.

You can use the same pattern for any other `R foo(V & v,Args...)` and
existent or non-existent `R(V::foo)(Args...)`. 
If `R` is not default-constructible, or if you want the default `R` that
is returned when `R(V::foo)` does not exist to be something different from
`R()`, then define a function `detail::fallback` (or whatever) that returns the 
desired default `R` and specify it instead of `detail::default_ctor`

How nice it would be it you could further template-paramaterize the pattern
to accomodate *any* possible member function of `T` with any possible return
type `R`. But the additional template parameter you would need for that would
be `R(T::*)(typename...)`,and its instantiating value would have to be
`&V::get` (or whatever), and then the pattern would
force you into the fatal snare of mentioning the thing whose existence is in doubt.

Comment: very nice answer, exactly explains the possibilities and impossibilities.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is more or less possible. It is known as a "member detector". See this wikibooks [link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Member_Detector) for how to accomplish this with macros. The actual implementation will depend on whether you are using pre- or post-C++11 and which compiler you are using.

Comment: Also, your post is a possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence/9154394

Comment: "expression compiles" and "member function exists" aren't really the same at all

Comment: this member detector is a good start. i just thought that a universal solution could be possible.

Comment: @sp2danny ah yes, my mistake. I guess the question is why would the expression not compile correctly then? Could the problem be reduced to member detection? ie, code that evaluates if particular member(s) exists then evaluate expression, otherwise some default expression.
I think I would also benefit from tly expanding on the question.